# How to use hash table with multiple keys

Tags: ruby

Considering creating a hash table:

```
a_Min   a_Max   b_Min   b_Max   p1   p2    p3     p4      p5       p6
40.000  47.95   -95.0   -74.01  12.8 6.5 177.82 0.9150   68.62    0.9020
42.000  47.95   -68.0   -59.50  11.0 5.8 185.20 0.9377   -11.80   0.9538
44.000  47.95   -74.2   -68.05  12.8 6.5 157.45 0.9194   37.55    0.9297
46.000  66.00   -59.5   -51.00  8.8  3.7 164.96 0.9465   -207.54  1.0342
47.951  66.00   -79.0   -59.55  12.8 6.5 157.45 0.9194   37.55    0.9297
47.951  66.00   -95.0   -79.01  12.8 6.5 177.82 0.9150   68.62    0.9020
...
```

if giving any `(a,b)`, it will fall within the four boundary control values in the hash table `(a_Min, a_Max, b_min, b_Max)` and returns its relative parameters `(p1, p2, p3....)`

I am trying something like this:

```
def functionXXX(a, b)
    threshold = XXX
    for t in threshold do   
       if (t[:a_Min]<=a && a<t[:a_Max] && t[:b_Min]<=b && b<t[:b_Max]) then
          return t
          break
       end
    end
end
```

Is this the correct way to do this task?

Comment: could you give more clues? i mean what is the relation between those rows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". As is we can't duplicate any problem because your code and question won't run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more elegant:

```
if (t[:a_Min]...t[:a_Max]).include? a &&
        (t[:b_Min]...t[:b_Max]).include? b
    # ...
end
```

Notice the three dots—if you want to include the last number, you would use `..`, but you've used `<` in your post.

It would be a better idea to store these as ranges in the first place, so you don't have to rebuild them every time you call the function.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! getting loving ruby now :)